# Messaging Center is not trigger on PageModel Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have an ZXing scanner page,I want to get the scan data from ScanPageModel to MyPageModel

I am opening scan page From MyPageModel

```
public Command ScanCode
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPageModel>(this, "ScanText", (value) =>
                    {

                    });
                    await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<ScanPageModel>();

                });
            }
        }
```

after getting the scan result from ScanPageModel send the messaging center data

```
 private void ScanResultAction(object obj)
        {
            // Prevent multiple event triggers from triggering the navigation multiple times
            if (NavigatingAway)
                return;

            NavigatingAway = true;          
            var result = obj as ZXing.Result;
            var format = result?.BarcodeFormat.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            var value = result?.Text ?? string.Empty;
            // Navigate to a page based on value
            SampleListData sa = new SampleListData();
            sa.Name = value;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<ScanPageModel, string>(this, "ScanText", result.Text);
                await CoreMethods.PopPageModel();
            });
        }
```

But my messaging center not called after sending data from ScanPageModel
Here is the Subscribe method for receiving Scan Code

```
public MyPageModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SampleListData>(this, "ScanText", (value) =>
            {

            });
        }
```

I also tried to place this subscribe inside

```
 public override void Init(object initData)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SampleListData>(this, "ScanText", (value) =>
                {

                });
        }
```

But its also not working
So How to solve this?

Comment: Send<T> and Subscribe<T> need to use the same Type for T - the type Sending the message

Answer (score 0):

Your subscribe and send methods are not the same. You send a message, but never listen to it. On the other hand you are subscribing to a message that you never send. Let me explain.

There are [2 types of Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center):

**1. Simple String Message (without arguments):**

*Subscribe:*

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "MyMessage", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "MyMessage" message is sent
});
```

*Send:*

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "MyMessage");
```

**2. Message with passing an argument:**

*Subscribe:*

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "MyMessageArg", (sender, arg) => {
    // do something whenever the "MyMessageArg" message is sent
    // using the 'arg' parameter which is a string
    string s = arg as string; // s = "John"
});
```

*Send:*

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string> (this, "MyMessageArg", "John");
```

---

Look what is inside <..> in these two types. In the 2nd type there is also a data type of the argument you want to send. And in your example you are mixing these two types. so change your subscribe method to:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SampleListData, string>(this, "ScanText", (sender, arg) =>{
     string data = arg as string;
     // do work
});
```

---

**Tips:**

- Don't have multiple *subscribe* methods with the same name
- Don't *subscribe* multiple times to the same message name!! Because if you run one *send* it will trigger every subscribe method you created (and that is very bad). Look out for subscribing on button clicks or in loops.
- If you are leaving the page that is subscribed to a message, then unsubscribe from the message (for performance and bugs)

**Unsubscribe**

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage> (this, "MyMessage");
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "MyMessageArg");
```